# Is it generally possible to cache an access token on a resource server (for a short time), even if it may expire?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Is it generally possible to cache an access token on a resource server, even if it may expire? There are no other resource servers involved and the token is only used for local operations (on the server) such as database persistence.

I have to cache the Access Token for at least 5 minutes (according to my IP). At the same time, it is only valid for 30 minutes. If a user goes to the backend just before the access token expires (e.g. in minute 29:59), the invalid token is cached and potentially used for another 5 minutes. For me it's okay because it's only some minutes and I just need the user context. But is this any problem from a technical point of view?

IP: OAuth 2.0

Frontend: Angular app sends the access token to the backend

Backend: .Net Core solution, uses token introspection to validate the token and get the user context

Comment: Frankly it sounds like you thought of everything here.

Comment: I had the idea to refresh the token from my Angular Client 5 minutes before it expires. This way I should always work with an valid access token.

Answer (score 1):

**INTROSPECTION AND RESULT CACHING**

When introspection is used, it is standard to cache the introspection results, to avoid calling the authorization server on every API request.

Introspection is often used with reference tokens, which are not readable like JWTs, and do not reveal any sensitive data to internet clients. Often an API gateway can do the introspection and maintain the cache.

Most caches support a time to live for each item. This should be set to a value that does not exceed the `exp` claim of the introspection response. The introspection results are then stored against a hash (eg SHA256) of the access token.

The Angular app should send the token on every API request. If the Angular app does not send a token whose hash matches one in the cache, or if introspection fails, the call is rejected with a 401 error.

**JWT RESPONSE**

A more complete security option, when supported, is for a gateway to do introspection with a different accept header, to receive a JWT response. The JWT access token can then be forwarded to the API. The API then validates the JWT on every request. Introspection differences are described in the [JWT Response Mode](https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-introspection-response-12.html) specification.

This method ensures secure verification on every request, especially in use cases where microservices forward the access token to each other. The JWT validation in each API then helps to protect against malicious requests inside the network.

**EXPIRY**

When the access token expires, or fails introspection for other reasons, eg the token has been revoked, a 401 error should be returned from the API. The Angular client must then try to refresh the token and retry the API request. If this fails, the client should redirect the user to re-authenticate.